# Error Logs in Apache2/Redhat_5.5 - Where?

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat

What is the directory path to the error logs for an Apache2/Redhat5.5 setup?

Also, something is wrong with my ~Google search strategy where I could not find this answer in less then 20 minutes? I.e., where should I be looking for configuration settings that are particular to Apache2/Redhat5.5 configurations?

Answer (score 3):

By default it's `/var/log/httpd/`

It's not default, it's redhat-specific. Other distros may have `/var/log/apache2/` (Ubuntu/Debian) or `/var/log/apache/`. It's usually possible to check contents of the package to find log dir location. On rpm-based distros you can do it with following command: `rpm -ql httpd | grep log`. On my system it prints out number of files & directories and it's easy to realize that `/var/log/httpd/` is what we are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the same for all or most Apache configurations on Linux or is this particular to RedHat5.5?

Comment: That is specific on Red Hat. For Ubuntu/Debian, its /var/log/apache2, and so does SLES.